# what is \kern good for

Tags: kerning, primitives

What is `\kern` instruction good for and how is it defined?
I cannot find it in Knuth's book TeXbook.

Comment: First part of the question: Take a look at the results of a search for "keming" on the search engine of your choice (image search can turn out to be quite hilarious). Second part: `\kern` is a primitive, not a macro, so in TeX (the language) it is defined as `\kern`.

Comment: The control sequence `kern` should be in the index of the TeXbook, marked with an asterisk to indicate that it is a primitive.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A "kern" is a typographic term for a nonbreakable space between two items. These items are usually, but not exclusively, glyphs.

`\kern` is a TeX primitive that serves to insert nonbreakable space. E.g., `a\kern3pt b` inserts `3pt` of nonbreakable space between `a` and `b`. `\kern` may occur in either horizontal mode (to insert horizontal space) or vertical mode (to insert vertical space). Something that `\kern` can do but which is not feasible in traditional, i.e., metal-based, typography is to set a *negative* kerning amount. E.g., `\kern-1em` deletes rather than inserts 1em of space.

> I cannot find [the term] in Knuth's book TeXbook.

That's quite puzzling. The TeXbook's index states that `\kern` occurs on pp. 10, 40, 66, 75, 87, 168, 256, 263, 280, 306, 389, 395-395, 416, 424, and 454-455. In addition, according to the book's index, the word "kerns" occurs on pp. 4, 66, 75, 95-97, 110, 157, 168, 280, 286, 306, 444, and 454-455.

Comment: To be more precise I couldn't have found the definition of `\kern` because it is in so many places in the TeXbook!

Comment: @user2925716 - Since `\kern` is not a macro but a "primitive" instruction, it's not formally defined *anywhere* in Volume A of "Computers and Typesetting,Volume A", aka "The TeXbook". To find the exact algorithm that defines a TeX primitive, one must consult "Computers and Typesetting, Volume B", aka "TeX: The Program". That said, the entry for `\kern` on p. 280 of the TeXbook (the page number is underlined in the index) comes pretty darn close to a formal definition this primitive.